# HTC One Permission Denial when launching LaunchActivity

Tags: android-intent, permissions, calendar

Until now it seemed to work when launching the LaunchActivity to open the Calendar App on HTC device.
Since HTC One now I'm getting a lot of error reports where this Exception is logged:

```
Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=com.htc.calendar/.LaunchActivity } 
from ProcessRecord{43523698 21358:de.superfusion.sdt.ad/u0a10073} 
(pid=21358, uid=10073) requires com.htc.permission.APP_DEFAULT
```

I have added the permission com.htc.permission.APP_DEFAULT to the AndroidManifest.xml but without success.
I really have no clue what to do to open the stock calendar app on HTC One.

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question by myself:

What i found out is, that on the HTC One the activity to start the calendar app has changed

from

```
**com.htc.calendar.LaunchActivity**
```

to

```
**com.htc.calendar.CalendarActivityMain**
```